# How do i check if an instance is in the terminating state?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

This returns InstanceStatuses:

```
aws ec2 describe-instance-status --include-all-instances --instance-ids i-123123123
```

Which looks like:

```
{
    "InstanceStatuses": [
        {
            "AvailabilityZone": "us-west-2a",
            "InstanceId": "i-123123123",
            "InstanceState": {
                "Code": 16,
                "Name": "running"
            },
            "InstanceStatus": {
                "Details": [
                    {
                        "Name": "reachability",
                        "Status": "passed"
                    }
                ],
                "Status": "ok"
            },
            "SystemStatus": {
                "Details": [
                    {
                        "Name": "reachability",
                        "Status": "passed"
                    }
                ],
                "Status": "ok"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

What does the state looks like when the instance is "terminating"? Not already terminated but pending termination? How can I check if an instance is in the pending termination state?